# java thread how to achieve concurrency

Tags: java, multithreading

I created a main class called X and two Y and Z classes. Y and Z implements Runnable classes. class X contains a static array A that can be accessed in Y and Z. The `run()` method of the class Y reads an input file and populates the vector A. The `run()` method of the Z class uses data stored into the vector A to process some data.

The objective of using threads in this problem is: as the vector A is filled in the `run()` method of class Y, the `run()` method of the class Z will processing the received values ​​in the vector A.

To do this I did the following calls in the main method of class X:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

Y objectY = new Y();           
Thread threadInput = new Thread(objectY );

threadInput.start();

Z objectZ = new Z();           
Thread threadOut = new Thread(objectZ);

threadOut.start();
```

Is that correct? I'm getting the expected results, but don't know if the code is parallelized in fact. If its not parallelized, how should I do it?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, your code does kick off two separate threads that operate in parallel with the main thread. I can't verify the correctness of the static array handling without seeing that code, but I can confirm that this is indeed parallelized.